# How to store static, but user-generated files on Heroku/Django

Tags: django, image, heroku, django-staticfiles, static-files

What's the best way to handle user-generated static files on Django/Heroku? The Django system for static files seems overly complicated (why do you need `collectstatic` at all?), plus `collectstatic` seems to only work for files which are known before you run the app, i.e. it doesn't handle any user-generated static files.

What is the best / canonical way to handle user-generated static files? Specifically, I'm looking to create thumbnails of some images, and I need to store them somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Django has a modular approach to it's design. Each application can have it's own static files. For example the Django admin interface has a bunch of css and images etc, other 3rd party applications you install may also have static assets. The aim of `collectstatic` is to collect all those assets into one central directory in production where Django itself would not serve static assets like it does in development but from something like Apache or Nginx.

Read up about it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

By user generated static content I guess you mean file uploads. These are different to static assets and are treated differently. Here you set a `MEDIA_ROOT` where media is uploaded too. I can't speak for Heroku but I think common practice is to upload media to an AWS S3 bucket. Checkout Django-Storages which has all sorts of File Storage backends for you to plug into. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-storages